# Exercise 3.1.b in Grimmett & Stirzaker's 'Probability and Random Processes'

Tags: probability, limits, taylor-expansion

The question asks "what value of the constant C do the following define mass function on the positive integers 1,2..."

Logarithmic

$$ f(x) = C 2^{-x}/x $$

The solution is ln(2) but I don't see how they calculated this.

The Taylor expansion of ln() around $a$ is:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n,$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x},\; f''(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2},\; f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{2}{x^3},\ldots,\; f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{x^n}.$$

so for $a = 1$,

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1},\; f''(x) = \frac{-1}{1^2},\; f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{2}{1^3},\ldots,\; f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{1^n}.$$

$$ln(x) = 0 + 1(x-1) - 1 \frac{(x-1)^2}{2!} + 2 \frac{(x-1)^3}{3!} $$

so for $x = 2$,

$$ln(2) = 0 + 1(1) - 1 \frac{(1)^2}{2!} + 2 \frac{(1)^3}{3!} $$

however this is not the same as which is given in the question:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2^1*1} + \frac{1}{2^2*2} + \frac{1}{2^3*3} $$

Can someone please explain how to calculate this?

Comment: Hint:  $\ln (1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^n}n$, now let $x=\frac 12$

Comment: You forgot to account for the $(n-1)!$ term in $f^{(n)}(x)$. That should cancel with the $n!$ in the denominator to leave just $n$ in the denominator, yielding you the series expansion that lulu mentioned above.